# Elements displayed differently in different browsers

Tags: html, css

http://eximi.dreamhosters.com/turbolingvo/quot_new.php

Step 2 and step 3 divs are supposed to be of the same height.
They are displayed as to be of the same height in Firefox, but in other browsers their heights differ.
What could cause it?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the world of web development ;P.

Comment: Thank you!
Loving it. :)

Answer (score 0):

The DIV is correct, in fact Chrome shows me the two divs have the same height, the problem is the inner FieldSet, you have no styles attached to it therefore they just grow as their content grows.